# fflush(stdin) not working in visual studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio

This code is not working as it worked in CodeBlocks :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char choice;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a character using getchar(): ");
        fflush(stdin);
        c = getchar();
        printf("The entered charcter is: ");
        putchar(c);
        do
        {
            printf("\nDo you want to continue [Y/N]: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            choice = getchar();
            if (choice >= 'a' && choice <= 'z')
                choice -= 32;
        } while (choice != 'Y' && choice != 'N');
        printf("\n");
    } while (choice == 'Y');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
Enter a character using getchar(): !
The entered character is: !
Do you want to continue [Y/N]:
Do you want to continue [Y/N]: y

Enter a character using getchar(): The entered character is:

Do you want to continue [Y/N]:
```

Why is fflush(stdin) not working ?

Is there any other way solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

`fflush(stdin)` is undefined, by the standard:

> J.2 Undefined behavior
>
> The stream for the fflush function points to an input stream or to an update stream in which the most recent operation was input (7.21.5.2).

So don't use it.

Comment: Other alternative to fflush(stdin)?

Comment: additional `getchar()` would obtain the `\n` for you

Comment: Then is there a way to only get the input and not the **\n**???